# tkinter: Using pack_forget and then pack() again, it packs in a different location

Tags: python, tkinter

In my understanding, using the pack() manager, each frame gets placed relative to the position of the other frames in the code. So if I do:

```
frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.pack()

frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
frame2.pack()

frame3 = tk.Frame(root)
frame3.pack()
```

Then `frame2` will appear below/after `frame1`, and before `frame3`.

My problem is when using the function `frame2.pack_forget()`, whenever I again do `frame2.pack()`, the order is not restored, but now I have `frame1`, `frame3`, `frame2`, as if `frame2` was the last one to `pack`.

How can I use `pack_forget()` and then `pack()` in the exactly same location it was created?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I use pack_forget() and then pack() in the exactly same location it was created?

In a broad sense, you can't. The very nature of `pack` is that it puts widgets along an edge of available space. When you add and remove widgets, the available space changes. When you call `pack_forget`, tkinter forgets where the widget was.

That being said, `pack` has options to help work around this. You can use the `before` and `after` options to insert the widget before or after some other widget in the packing order. It's up to you to remember the order. For example, you could do `frame2.pack(before=frame3)` to have it inserted before `frame3`.

If you want to hide and remove widgets dynamically, `grid` is usually the better choice because `grid_remove` will cause `grid` to remember where a widget was.